# Yii2 framework files deleted, but application still works

Tags: include, structure, composer-php, yii2

I'm developing a project with Yii2 in Eclipse IDE. Accidentally I deleted the Yii2 folder under vendor/yiisoft. But still my application works like a charme and it doesn't throw any exceptions. I used Composer installing http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-improved-basic-template/. The file Vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php returns an array that includes
`'yii\\' => array($vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2')`
Can anyone tell me where it includes the yii2 framework files from?

Comment: Seems like bug with IDE. Maybe folder was deleted from IDE, but in the actual file structure it still exists. Or did you mean you then retrieve it with composer? Application can't work without that folder. The files are included exactly from there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. At first I set up the application with composer (just to let you know what I did). Then I worked on it and deleted the Yii2 folder as mentioned above. I can state in windows explorer that it really doesn't exist anywhere in the application's file system but the application runs. This is so weird. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

It might be using the files from `cache`. Try flushing all your `cache` and if it still works. I doubt that it'll :P

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the problem by cloning the project to another folder and then copying back all files to the original folder. I still haven't got a clue why this strange behavior occured (every cache I know about was flushed). However, now it works as it should. Thanks for your help.